# Pandas csv to sqlite3 - sqlalchemy dtype ValueError

Tags: python, sqlite, pandas

I am trying to set the dtypes for columns in a table to be inserted into a sqlite file. I'm new to sqlalchemy and can't figure out how to set the dtype per column.

NOTE: I just made them all NUMERIC just to try to get it working. I will change them to what they need to be when I get passed the ValueError exception.

```
import pandas
import sqlite3
import sqlalchemy

conn = sqlite3.connect('finances.sqlite')

vang401k = pandas.read_csv('/Google Drive/PF/401k.csv')

dtypes = {
        'CreateDate': sqlalchemy.NUMERIC(),
        'Account': sqlalchemy.NUMERIC(),
        'Contributed': sqlalchemy.NUMERIC(),
        'MonthlyReturns': sqlalchemy.NUMERIC(),
        'Performance': sqlalchemy.NUMERIC(),
        'Totals': sqlalchemy.NUMERIC(),
        'MonthChange': sqlalchemy.NUMERIC(),
        'YTDReturn': sqlalchemy.NUMERIC(),
        'YTDROI': sqlalchemy.NUMERIC()
         }

vang401k.to_sql('vanguard401k', conn, if_exists='replace', index=False, dtype=dtypes)
```

This is throwing a ValueError exception

```
ValueError: YTDROI (NUMERIC) not a string
```

Am I missing something or have the format wrong for using sqlalchemy.types?

Also if I try 
`from sqlalchemy.types import String` and change all dtypes to

```
dtypes = {
            'CreateDate': String,
            'Account': String, ...
```

I get a different exception

```
ValueError: YTDROI (<class 'sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes.String'>) not a string
```

Also using Python 3.5.1 if that changes anything

Comment: This is a weird one.  What version of pandas and sqlachemy are you using?

Comment: panda '0.18.1' , sqlalchemy '1.0.13'

Comment: hmmm  maybe it doesn't like a sqlite connection with sqlalchemy dtypes  instead of `conn = sqlite3.connect('finances.sqlite')` try `conn = create_engine("sqlite:///finances")`  you'll need to do `from sqlalchemy import create_engine` as well.

Comment: Also, from the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)  `dtype : dict of column name to SQL type, default None
Optional specifying the datatype for columns. The SQL type should be a SQLAlchemy type, or a string for sqlite3 fallback connection.`  that last part about sqllite is interesting, but i'm not sure what it means

Comment: Well I think that fixed it. I still get an error when running but I think that has more to do with my actual data `StatementError: (builtins.ValueError) could not convert string to float: 'Mon Nov 30 2015 21:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)'` I need to figure out how to stop google sheets from changing to this from 2015-12-01 when exporting to csv.

Strange that I had to open it with create_engine to even use a sqlalchemy dtype. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Oh wait, I still have them all set to NUMERIC...

Comment: Ok, good deal.  The more I think about it, the more it makes sense.  Sqlalchemy types translate to the native db types based on the dialect of the connection